# Detect a click outside the component when two instances of same components are present in single page in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

i have a componenet which is rendered twice in the same page and each instance of componeent has a unique id. The click outside event i have used is :

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
  clickout(event) {
    if(this.eRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
      this.text = "clicked inside";
    } else {
      this.text = "clicked outside";
    }
  }
```

But this is not working when we are rendering two instances of the component in same page.

Could anyone suggest method to determine the click outside the component in this scenario

Comment: what is the exact issue you are facing ?

Comment: Do you want to detect the click outside both components or is each component dependant on its own?

Comment: check whether this is your expected behavior https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9n8pbm